# groups with identical sum but different proportions of the individual elements R

Tags: r

I have 8 groups (columns), each one consisting of 8 different molecules.

In the data frame the numbers represent the number of carbons in each molecule and each column is a group. I need to find what concentration of each molecule to use so that every group has the same sum of carbons at the end. I should get this result as proportion (20% of mol1, 25% mol2, etc). The final number of carbon atoms is irrelevant as long as it is the same for each column once every value has been multiplied by its proportion.

I would appreciate every insight! Thanks

```
data.frame(c(36,    12, 14, 4,  3,  8,  4   ,7), c(6,   12, 3,  4,  6,  4,   
8,  7), c(36,   7,  6,  4,  9,  8,  4,  7), c(6,    12, 12, 5,  4,  7,   
8,7), c( 36,    6,  3,  6,  4,  9,  4,  7), c(36,   5,  4,  6,  6,  3,  8,   
7),c(36,    12, 12, 14, 4,  6,  4,  7), c( 6,   6,  3,  4,  6,  8,  4,  7))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why the oddly formatted `data.frame`? Are the columns unnamed? Please add your expected output for the sample data you provide along with any code attempt.

Comment: See `?prop.table`

Comment: Hi! I actually have not even figured out how to start, that is why I started this post. I think however that computationally it is not very easy to do. I have thought about it long and mathematically what I want is an 8th order equation where the X1 - X8 are multiplying each of my elements from the columns. Do you think this is feasible in R?

Comment: See `?prop.table`. @G.Grothendieck: it does occur to me that `margin` is terribly explained in [prop.table's manpage](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/prop.table.html), worse than [apply manpage](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html). *"index, or vector of indices to generate margin for"* does not tell a new user much, unlike *"E.g., for a matrix 1 indicates rows, 2 indicates columns, c(1, 2) indicates rows and columns"*

Answer (score 0):

You can find least common multiple of column sum and find the necessary proportions as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(36, 12, 14, 4, 3, 8, 4, 7), b = c(6, 12, 
3, 4, 6, 4, 8, 7), c = c(36, 7, 6, 4, 9, 8, 4, 7), d = c(6, 12, 
12, 5, 4, 7, 8, 7), e = c(36, 6, 3, 6, 4, 9, 4, 7), f = c(36, 
5, 4, 6, 6, 3, 8, 7), g = c(36, 12, 12, 14, 4, 6, 4, 7), h = c(6, 
6, 3, 4, 6, 8, 4, 7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

library(numbers)
c_amt <- colSums(df)
LCM_c <- Reduce(LCM, c_amt, 1)
odds <- LCM_c / c_amt
props <- odds / sum(odds)  
library(scales)
percent_format()(props)
# [1] "9.5%"  "16.7%" "10.3%" "13.7%" "11.1%" "11.1%" "8.8%"  "18.9%"
```